# Can there exist $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that $X_n \to -\infty$ a.s. and $EX_n\to 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Can there exist variables $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that  $X_n \to -\infty$ a.s. and   $EX_n\to 0$?

How can we prove or disprove this analytically?

Comment: Please share some of your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be $-n$ with probability $p_n$ and $e^{n}$ with probability $1-p_n$ where $p_n=e^{n}/(n+e^{n})$ . To show that this example works note that $\sum (1-p_n)<\infty$ and use Borel Cantelli Lemma.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly simpler example than Kavi's, which avoids Borel-Cantelli.

Fix a random variable $U \sim U(0,1)$ and let
$$X_n = \begin{cases} n^2-n ,& U < \frac{1}{n} \\ -n , & U \ge \frac{1}{n}. \end{cases}$$
You can easily check that $E[X_n]=0$.  And on the event $U > 0$, which has probability 1, we have $X_n = -n$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and therefore $X_n \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the random variables with $P(\xi_n=2^n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $P(\zeta_n=\frac{-2^n}{2^n-1})=\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$ and put $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i$. Note that $E\xi_i=0$ for all $i$. Moreover $P(\xi_i>0 \quad \text{i.o})=0$ by Borel Cantelli. In particular $\xi_i<0$ eventually with probability one. Hence $X_n\to -\infty$ a.s.